# How to write an Android bug report to a file via ADB?

Tags: android, adb

When I go to report an issue to the [Android Open-source Project (AOSP) issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/), it asks me to attach a bug report.

How do I generate this bug report via ADB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With your device attached, from the command-line (where ADB is accessible) run:

```
adb bugreport
```

This will generate a text file with the above name in the same directory, which you can then attached to the issue.  Be patient, it may take 10 seconds or more to generate.

**EDIT August 29, 2017**

As @dharmin007 pointed out, the [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html) now says the following:

> With only one device connected to your computer, execute the following:

> `adb bugreport E:\Reports\MyBugReports`

> This example specifies an optional path to the bugreport option where the bug report is saved.

> With multiple devices connected, you must specify the device. Run the following adb commands to get the device serial number and generate the bug report.

> ```
>   $ adb devices
> ```

```
  List of devices attached
  emulator-5554      device
  8XV7N15C31003476 device
```

> ```
>   $ adb -s 8XV7N15C31003476 bugreport
> ```
>
> This example does not specify the optional path, so the bug report is saved to the local directory

These commands will generate a zip file - for more information about the contents of the zip file see [Android Studio docs "Inspect the bug report ZIP file"](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html#bugreport).

Answer (score 13):

In case someone is looking for the bugreport for newer devices the command is

```
adb bugreport bugreport.zip
```